# Given $S \subset \Bbb{R}$, show $\textbf{int}(S)+\textbf{ext}(S)+\partial S =\Bbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

The way I proved it is that we knwo R is open so intR=R.

For any point in IntS is inside of IntR and any point in ExtS is inside of IntR.

any point that is neither intS nor extS is still inside of IntR

So intR is collection of all intS,extS,and boundary of S, which means R is union of intS extS and boundary of S

It seems like my proof is not complete, and cant be sure whether i can call it a proof,,

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Your argument shows only that $\operatorname{int}(S)\cup\operatorname{ext}(S)+\partial S\subseteq \mathbb R$, which is trivial. The substantial part is the other direction. What you need to prove is that every $x$ is either an interior point, an exterior point, or a boundary point of $S$. Do you have definitions of these concepts?

Comment: Hi @Kaytlyn, consider that some authors define $\partial S$ as the complement of $\text {int} S+\text {ext} S$ (for example Spivak in his book "Calculus on manifolds"). What's your definition of $\partial S$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\text{ext}(S), \space \text{int}(S), \space \partial S \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ it follows that the union $$\text{ext}(S) \cup \text{int}(S) \cup  \partial S \subseteq \Bbb{R}$$ Now you need to show the reverse inclusion. Recall: $$\text{ext}(S) = \Bbb{R} \setminus \overline{S} \\ \text{int}(S) =\Bbb{R} \setminus \overline{\text{ext}(S)} \\ \text{and} \quad \partial S = \overline{S}\setminus \text{int}(S)$$ Now let $x \in \Bbb{R}$. It should be clear that $x \in \overline{S}$ or $x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \overline{S}$, as $\Bbb{R} = \overline{S} \cup \left(\Bbb{R} \setminus \overline{S}\right)$. If $x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \overline{S}$ then $x \in \text{ext}(S)$ by definition. Else, $x \in \Bbb{R}\setminus \text{ext}(S)$ Can you argue from here that either $x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \overline{\text{ext}(S)}$ or $x \in \overline{S} \setminus \text{int}(S)$? It may be helpful to note that  $$\Bbb{R} \setminus \overline{\text{ext}(S)} \subseteq \Bbb{R} \setminus \text{ext}(S)$$

Comment: Why intS=R-extS?? Can there be a boundary point in R-extS?

Comment: @Kaytlyn Not quite, the interior of $S$ is the complement of the *closure* of the exterior of $S$, notated as $\Bbb{R} \setminus \overline{\text{ext}(S)}$. That is just a definition. However, every boundary point of $S$ will be contained in $ \Bbb{R} \setminus \text{ext}(S)$ because $$ \Bbb{R} \setminus \text{ext}(S) =  \Bbb{R} \setminus \left(\Bbb{R} \setminus \overline{S} \right) = \overline{S} \supseteq \partial S$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be any subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is any point, then one of three mutually exclusive things can happen:

1. There is some $r > 0$ such that $(x - r, x +r) \subseteq S$. Then by definition, $x \in \operatorname{int}(S)$.
2. There is some $r > 0$ such that $(x -r, x + r) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus S$. Then $x \in \operatorname{int}(\mathbb{R}\setminus S) = \operatorname{ext}(S)$.
3. For all $r>0$, $(x-r, x+r) \nsubseteq S$ and $(x-r, x+r) \nsubseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus S$, or equivalently, for all $r>0$, $(x-r,x+r) \cap S \neq \emptyset$ and $(x-r,x+r) \cap \mathbb{R}\setminus S \neq \emptyset$. This by definition means $x \in \partial S$.

So $x$ is always in one of the three sets, and these sets are disjoint. Of course, any of them can be empty, or even two of them (for $S = \mathbb{Q}$ the interior and exterior are empty, and all points of $\mathbb{R}$ are boundary points).